# Sencha touch grid Summaryrow values disappering

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha touch grid and I am facing one issue in the development.
The issue is, if I reorder the columns of the grid using ViewOption plugin, the SummaryRow values get disappered. How do I retain the summary row values after Column reordering?
I am using Sencha touch 2.3.x

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading the sources and I don't think Grid is finished.

What I found is the [ViewOptions.onColumnReorder](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/source/ViewOptions.html#Ext-grid-plugin-ViewOptions-method-onColumnReorder) apparently only change the DOM elements order and not the store order. And reading the [SummaryRow.updateGrid](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/source/SummaryRow.html#Ext-grid-plugin-SummaryRow-method-updateGrid) I didn't find any bind with both. SummaryRow only bind with store and add/remove/etc columns (not reorder).

I can be wrong, I didnt try grid yet. But I guess your best shot is try to force the [SummaryRow.doUpdateSummary](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/source/SummaryRow.html#Ext-grid-plugin-SummaryRow-method-doUpdateSummary) after the onColumnReorder.

Comment: Thanks Scoup, Your answer helped me.I used Ext.getCmp("SummaryRowID").doUpdateSummary();